# How to set up a default (root, /, index) WEB application in Caché?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

Having the REST application set up, or having the `index.html` file displaying application under `CSP Files` directory, is it even possible to set this WEB application as a default one for the server?

In other words, how to display the application by querying `http://localhost`, but not `http://localhost/AppName/` or `http://localhost/index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is likely to setup routing rules in the Apache server that is started with the instance.

Comment: Thanks! That is good point to edit Apaché's config to set `DirectoryIndex index.html`. I had only the last hope that it can be set internally somewhere in Caché.

Answer (score 1):

Having the RESTful application, you need to name your WEB-application as '/', and create the route with the same name inside the dispatch class:

```
<Routes>
   <Route Url="/" Method="GET" Call="Index"/>
   ...
</Routes>
```

...and then implement the Index method as you desire.

In case of the `index.html` file - I believe that there is someone other who know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve it with internal Apache, you just only need to create root WebApplication in Caché. As well as I'm sure you already did it before like `/AppName/`, just create with name `/`.

If you want to do it with external Apache, then I hope you already have [properly](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCGI_ux) configured one. Just what you need then, is to add such lines

```
<Location />
  CSP on
  SetHandler csp-handler-sa
</Location>
```

In you REST class, you must be already know, that Route map uses regexp to get correct method. So, in routes map you can change it so

```
<Routes>
   <Route Url="/(index\.html)?" Method="GET" Call="Index"/>
   <!-- or something like this, to catch all static for one method -->
   <Route Url="/((?!rest/).*)" Method="GET" Call="GetStatic"/>
   ...
</Routes>
```

Comment: That's a good point about regex in UrlMap, thanks! In my case, `index.html` meant the physical file in one of CSP sub-directories. @joeb suggested changing the Apache setting to read html index files - that's it, wondering if this is the only way to enable reading html index files in Caché.

Comment: When you set `CSP on`, then `DirectoryIndex` will be ignored, and every request will be sent directly to Cache, without any modifications. In my projects I use such way, and return static files from disk, but with Cache not apache. You can see my class as an example [here](https://github.com/daimor/CacheBlocksExplorer/blob/master/Blocks%2FRouter.cls.xml) method `GetStatic`, it returns files from disk in development mode, and from `XData`, in production.

Comment: That's it, but it still leaves the necessity to query `http://example.com/index.html` instead of just `http://example.com` without redefining paths programmatically as you did in GetStatic, isn't it?

Comment: `index.html` came from apache, where this name was in `DirectoryIndex` by default, and then with used as index.php. And nowadays, it doesn't matter what appear in a browser's address field. And we can just forgot about `index.html` and ignore it. It leaves just for memory about old times. :)

Comment: I am sure people who like vanilla URLs won't agree with this. Furthermore, typing the name of the site and getting the message "404" is more than strange. Let's leave this topic in advantage of `DirectoryIndex` Apache's option.